# ChromeでWebページ全体を印刷する方法

Tags: google-chrome

こんにちは。
現在HTMLで大きなサイズ（例えば横がA4で3ページで縦がA4で4ページとか）のWebページを作っているのですが、そのページ全体を印刷しようとしても、chromeだと左のA41枚分の幅しか印刷できません（縦は4ページ分印刷できる）。chromeでページ全体を印刷する方法はないでしょうか。拡張機能またはJavascriptでの対応なんでも構いませんので教えてください。

Comment: 可能かどうかはさておき、具体的な印刷イメージを質問に追記するとよいかもしれません。例) 縦A4 4ページ、横A4 3ページ分(1188mm x 630mm)のWebページをA4縦1枚に印刷 etc.

Comment: Chromeの印刷で「PDFに保存」を選択し、用紙をA0に設定してから「印刷」をクリックしてください。そうするとA0サイズ(A4を4x4に並べたサイズ）のPDFが得られます。このPDFファイルをAcrobat Readerで開いて、複数のA4用紙に印刷すれば全体を印刷したものが得られます。（kinko'sなど大判印刷をしてくれる店にPDFを持ち込めば、A0サイズの紙に印刷してもらう事も可能です。(A0だと、１枚１万円ぐらいかな？))

Comment: A0固定で良いならCSSで`@media print { @page { size: 841mm 1189mm } }`と指定する方法もありそうですね。